# Напечатать те слова из введенного предложения, в которых есть удвоение букв, или вывести сообщение об их отсутствии

Tags: c, строки

Помогите решить это задание. Долго над ним сижу не могу понять как правильно сделать. Пробовал сделать как - то так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LEN 100
#define SIZE 100

void main(void)
{
    int i = 0, k = 0, j = 0, s[LEN], s1[LEN][SIZE];
    gets(s);
    while (s[k] != '\0') {
        if (s[k] != ' ')
        {
            s1[i][j] = s[k];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
        else {
            s1[i][j] = '\0';
            for (j = 0; s1[i][j] != '\0'; j++) {
                if (s1[i][j] == s1[i][j + 1]) {
                    printf("%c", s1[i][j]);
                }
            }
            j = 0; 
            i++;
        }
    }
    _getch();
}
```

Помогите плиз. Очень надо.

Comment: В чём заключается собственно вопрос? Что именно не работает или работает не так как надо в указанном вами коде?

Comment: Программа не работает так как надо в моем коде.

Comment: Наверное, стоит начать с того, что `char * gets ( char * str );`, а Вы ему скармливаете массив `int`.

Comment: А точно, но все равно программа работает неправильно.

Comment: Начните с использования *strsep()*. Когда код будет проще — проще найти и проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s[300];
    int  hasDoubles = 0;
    gets_s(s,300);
    for(char * word = strtok(s," \r\n\t.,"); word != NULL;
        word = strtok(NULL," \r\n\t.,"))
    {
        int dblIn = 0;

        for(char * с = word;*c;++c)
            if(*c == *(c+1)) { dblIn = 1; break; }

        if (dblIn)
        {
            printf("%s\n",word);
            hasDoubles = 1;
        }
    }

    if (hasDoubles == 0) puts("No doubles!");

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можно ли как-то вашу программу написать без использования функции, потому что мне нельзя ее использовать в программе?

Comment: Ну это же очень просто - перенести ее на место вызова. Я исправил ответ, посмотрите - просто перенес код и все.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.